# Function in array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, invocation

How can I set value of the `input` boxes? When my code runs the `gng()` function is not working. I just see the value of `input` box as the string `"gng()"`.

```
<div id="yeni" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 30px; width: 700px; height: 400px; "> </div>


<script>
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  var tr = [];
  var td = [];
  var rowcount = 5;
  var columncount = 3;
  var dataarray = [["1", "red", " <input value=\"gng(9,5)\">"],
      ["2", "white", " <input value=\"gng(3,5)\">"],
      ["3", "black", " <input value=\"gng(4,5)\">"],
      ["4", "green", " <input value=\"gng(1,5)\">"],
      ["5", "gray", " <input value=\"gng(2,5)\">"]]

  for(s = 0; s < rowcount; s++) {
    tr[s] = document.createElement('tr');
    for(i = 0; i < columncount; i++) {
      td[i] = document.createElement('td');
      td[i].innerHTML = dataarray[s][i];
      tr[s].appendChild(td[i]);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr[s]);
  }
  document.getElementById('yeni').appendChild(tbl);
  function gng(a, b) {var c = a / b;return c;}
</script>
```

Comment: What is that `binds` and how is it used in Your code? Are You using some king of framework? Can You show more complete code?

Answer (score 1):

`" <input value=\"gng(9,5)\">"` is a string, which means it is just literal text data, including `gng(9,5)` in the string does not invoke `gng`. Instead you will need to concatenate the surrounding parts of the string around an invocation `' <input value="' + gng(9,5) + '">'`. You'll notice I replaced the double quotes around your string with single quotes; in JS single quotes and double quotes do the same thing. If you use single quotes you don't have to escape the double quotes in your string.

So, the full code would look like this:

```js
function gng(a, b) {
  var c = a / b;
  return c;
}

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
var tr = [];
var td = [];
var i; // remember to declare all variables!
var s; // without declaring s and i they are implicit globals!
var rowcount = 5;
var columncount = 3;
var dataarray = [
    ["1", "red", ' <input value="' + gng(9,5) + '">'],
    ["2", "white", ' <input value="' + gng(3,5) + '">'],
    ["3", "black", ' <input value="' + gng(4,5) + '">'],
    ["4", "green", ' <input value="' + gng(1,5) + '">'],
    ["5", "gray", ' <input value="' + gng(2,5) + '">']
  ];

for(s = 0; s < rowcount; s++) {
  tr[s] = document.createElement('tr');
  for(i = 0; i < columncount; i++) {
    td[i] = document.createElement('td');
    td[i].innerHTML = dataarray[s][i];
    tr[s].appendChild(td[i]);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tr[s]);
}
document.getElementById('yeni').appendChild(tbl);
```

```html
<div id="yeni" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 30px; width: 700px; height: 400px; "> </div>
```

If you are targeting browsers that support [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you could inline it instead:

```
["1", "red", `<input value="${gng(9,5)}">`],
```

If I were writing this, I would have done it a little differently. Instead of `for`, I would have used the [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the array of data:

```js
function gng(a, b) {
  var c = a / b;
  return c;
}

var tbl = document.createElement('table'),
  dataArray = [
    ["1", "red", ' <input value="' + gng(9,5) + '">'],
    ["2", "white", ' <input value="' + gng(3,5) + '">'],
    ["3", "black", ' <input value="' + gng(4,5) + '">'],
    ["4", "green", ' <input value="' + gng(1,5) + '">'],
    ["5", "gray", ' <input value="' + gng(2,5) + '">']
  ];

dataArray.forEach(function (row) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  row.forEach(function (data) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = data;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });
  tbl.appendChild(tr);
});

document.getElementById('yeni').appendChild(tbl);
```

```html
<div id="yeni" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 30px; width: 700px; height: 400px; "> </div>
```

Doing this lets you eliminate some variable and make the code easier to read and understand. It also makes it more maintainable into the future because you no longer need to remember to manually update the column and row counts if you change the data array.

Comment: firstl many many thanks, but my code little bit is different when I see  your answer  I realise that  when I make it basic ,codes little change .So it is not exactly met  my problem. How can ı send you my all codes